# How to check if data is coming from gps device to servers tcp port in Windows service?

Tags: c#, tcp

I an developing a Windows service that will be used to read data coming from GPS device. Data is coming on servers port and then processed further. I am using the Following method to read data from TCP port.

```
public void Starter()
    {
        try
        {
            logsys.Enqueue("Service started");
            //Setup the socket and message buffer
            tcpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            int cport = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CPORT"].ToString());
            tcpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CID"].ToString()), cport));
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            //td = new Thread(readdata);


            //Start listening for a new message.
            EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CID"].ToString()), cport);
            tcpSock.Connect(newClientEP);

            tcpSock.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock);


            //td.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logsys.Enqueue("GPS_Service Starter Error: " + ex.Message); 
        }
    }
```

But its not working. I am not getting any error, but data is also not receiving. I am not able to understand what is the issue. How can I check what's going wrong?

Comment: Why not use a TcpClient Object ? Tutorial [here](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/12/basic-tcp-socket-echo-client-server.html)

Comment: What is udpSock, and your callback function DoReceiveFrom()?

Comment: udpsock is object of Socket class  and DoReceiveFrom() is used for receiving data from GPS device continuosly.